# Cohen's d, but using mean absolute deviation

Tags: effect-size, cohens-d

A common measure of effect size used in the social sciences is to look at the standardized difference in means between two conditions (Cohen's d). That is, take the difference in means between two independent samples, and divide that number by their pooled standard deviation.

Here's my question. I wonder if you can calculate a similar statistic, but instead of using the pooled standard deviation, to use the pooled mean absolute deviation? There is some empirical work suggesting that people often interpret standard deviations as mean absolute deviations [1]. Plus, it strikes me that an effect size normalized over mean absolute deviations would be more intuitive/easier to understand than Cohen' d. Instead of thinking of effect size in terms of standardized units, you would instead think in terms of differences normalized over the mean spread.

So, I'm wondering if there are good mathematical reasons why one would want to use SDs instead mean absolute deviations? Please forgive me if this is a sophomoric question, my mathematical intuitions are fairly limited.

[1] Goldstein, D. G. & Taleb, N. N. (2007). We don't quite know what we are talking about when we talk about volatility. Journal of Portfolio Management, 33(4), 84-86.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: "difference in means between two independent samples, and divide that number by their pooled standard deviation." can you clarify how this is different from the test statistic for the t-test.

Comment: AdamO: my (very limited) understanding is that effect sizes such as Cohen's d are descriptive statistics -- they tell you how big an effect is. T-statistics, of course, are used for drawing statistical inferences. So t-statistics depend on the standard error of the mean, while Cohen's d does not. That said, one can calculate Cohen's d directly from the t-statistic and the sample size.

Comment: Cohen seems to have defined $d$ not in terms of pooled standard deviation, but $\sigma$. For example, see the table on p157 [here](http://classes.deonandan.com/hss4303/2010/cohen%201992%20sample%20size.pdf). Given that you're using a definition that doesn't seem to be Cohen's (though doubtless based on it), can you point to (or include) exactly what the definition is?

Comment: Glen_b: Here's what I mean by pooled standard deviation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_standard_deviation. This is what is commonly used in the denominator when calculating Cohen's d.